# vtkDelaunay3D save triangulation

Tags: c++, vtk, triangulation, delaunay, qvtkwidget

I am using VTK to generate a 3D Delaunay triangulation from a list of input points that are obtained using terrestrial laser scanner. So far, I successfully generated some 3D triangulations and saved them in .vtk or .vtu file formats. However, I need to save them as one of the popular formats such as .ply, .stl, .obj or .wrl. Could you please tell me how can I save 3d triangulation in one of these formats? My other question is about setAlpha and setTolerance parameters, could you please explain me these parameters in detail?
Thanks in advance

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    //load the point cloud
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkSimplePointsReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSimplePointsReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName("kucuk50k.xyz");
    reader->Update();
    vtkPolyData* polydata = reader->GetOutput();
    std::cout << "The point cloud is loaded" << std::endl;
    //end of point cloud loading
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    // Generate a mesh from the input points. If Alpha is non-zero, then
    // tetrahedra, triangles, edges and vertices that lie within the
    // alpha radius are output.
    std::cout << "Start delaunay 3d triangulation" << std::endl;
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDelaunay3D> delaunay3DAlpha = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDelaunay3D>::New();
    delaunay3DAlpha->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
    delaunay3DAlpha->SetAlpha(0.01);
    std::cout << "3d Delaunay computed" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Start writing the triangulation" << std::endl;
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter> ugWriter =    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter>::New();
    ugWriter->SetInputConnection(delaunay3DAlpha->GetOutputPort());
    ugWriter->SetFileName("delaunayy_50k.vtk");
    ugWriter->Write();
    std::cout << "VTK file created" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to compute a triangular surface from a scanned terrain, right? Is there a good reason to use 3D Delaunay which creates tetrahedra instead of 2.5D Delaunay? You may have a look at my [Fade2.5D](http://www.geom.at/fade25d/html/) library, there is a free student version. A limitation of 2.5D is however that you can't represent vertical walls and thus buildings are not directly supported.

[image]

Comment: My data is not scanned terrain. It is composed of various building facedes.